# VirtualBox: mount USB in macOS High Sierra

Tags: hard-drive, usb, mount, virtualbox

I'm running **VirtualBox 5.2.8** on **my Mac High Sierra 10.13.3.** The **guest OS is also macOS High Sierra 10.13.3**.

My external SSD is unmounted from my host system and is correctly mounted as USB 3.0 with filter to VirtualBox. However, the drive does not show up in my guest OS. `diskutil list` does not list the drive, but my drive does show up in the guest OSs System Information.

How can I fix this issue?

Looking forward to your response.

**EDIT**

I noticed that only my portable Samsung SSD (format: Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled)) is not recognised by my guest OS. However, it works just fine on my host system. Other usb sticks with the same format are recognised.

Comment: Does it show up as being recognized by the system?  What do you see when you run `dmesg` after plugging in the drive?

Comment: @Allan Wow, I found something with `dmesg`.
    ``USBMSC Identifier (non-unique): S25JNYAG800300H 0x4e8 0x8001 0x1, 3
    USB device 04E880010C90000 - will be reset!
    USBMSC Identifier (non-unique): S25JNYAG800300H 0x4e8 0x8001 0x1, 3``
The displayed uid matches with the one of my Samsung SSD